# JSON not returning the actual data from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to build a basic covid19 website. the code I am using is only returning [object Object] in the actual data. What I am doing wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the documentation for [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: And/or [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: You can't show an object in the DOM, try replacing `$("div").append(field + " ");` with `console.log(field);` you will see the data is correct, to use individual items you can use for example `field.NewConfirmed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", function(result){
      $.each(result.Countries, function(i, field){
        $("div").append("<span>"+JSON.stringify(field)+"</span></br>");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to append JavaScript object to DOM. Instead, see what data you're getting (as someone mentioned in comments, by `console.log`) then you can edit your append part accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a sample answer which appends all list of country. Understand each and every line and function how it works. I have appended list of country, how to render the rest items that I leave it to you. Don't get discouraged or disappointed; learning to code is a journey, not destination.

**Note**:https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ is added if you are running it in your localhost to avoid CORS's problem. If you have hosted the page, you can remove it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on('click',function(){
    $.getJSON("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.covid19api.com/summary", function(result){
               var obj=result;
               var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
               var s = JSON.parse(json);
               s.Countries.map(function(c){
                     $("#result").append("<span>"+c.Country+"</span></br>");
               })
               console.log(s.Countries[0].Country);
    });
  });
});
```